# Select and Insert if two conditions are met

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

We are trying to create a conditional statement but are not sure where to begin. The logic is this:

If (Col.A = Col.B) AND (Col.C = Col.D) THEN Select Data FROM Col.G and INSERT INTO Col.H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have headers or titles at the top of your columns, enter this formula into cell H2:

```
=REPT(G2,(A2=B2)*(C2=D2))
```